# Trying to build a VBA script

Tags: excel, vba, process, populate

Hi there I have no background knowledge in to how to build an VBA scipt. i have the following requirments for my script
The script should scan per user to find which numbers are associated with that user. The numbers that could be associated consist of numbers numbered between 1 and 23 with an optional "+" or "-" sign. Specifically, the following numbers can be found (1, -1, 2, -2, 3, -3, 4, -4, 5, -5, 6, -6, 7, -7, 8, -8, 9, -9, 10, -10, 11, -11, 12, -12, 13, -13, 15, -15, 16, -16, 18, -18, 20, -20, 21, -21, 22, -22, 23, -23). The script reads each row to determine which numbers appear in that row under columns AQ, AU, AY, BC, BE, BV, BZ, CD, CF. This is done for rows 5 to 75. After scanning all the numbers that appeared, the script then moves to columns CQ to DT.
For the following numbers, a 1 should be placed in the next column if found in the respective row, and a 0 if the code is not found in the respective row: 1 in CG, -1 in CH, 2 in CI, -2 in CJ, 3 in CK, -3 in CL, 4 in CM, -4 in CN, 5 in CO, -5 in CP, 6 in CQ, -6 in CR, 7 in CS, -7 in CT, 8 in CU, -8 in CV, 9 in CW, -9 in CX, 10 in CY, -10 in CZ, 11 in DA, -11 in DB, 12 in DC, -12 in DD, 13 in DE, -13 in DF, 15 in DG, -15 in DH, 16 in DI, -16 in DJ, 18 in DK, -18 in DL, 20 in DM, -20 in DN, 21 in DO, -21 in DP, 22 in DQ, -22 in DR, 23 in DS, -23 in DT.
Example: If the number "7" appears in row 8 under column AQ, then a "1" is placed in row 7 under column CS. If, for example, the number "9" did not appear in row 8 under the aforementioned columns (AQ, AU, AY, BC, BE, BV, BZ, CD, CF), then a "0" is placed in row 8 under column CW.
If a number appears multiple times in a row, the script should not place a "1" under the corresponding column for that number but instead should place the number of occurrences. For example, if the number "4" appears 3 times in row 17, the script places the number "3" under column CM in row 17.
The script should account for sensitivity to "+" and "-" signs that may precede a number.

I've asked AI and AI has come up with the following script

```
Sub ProcessDataAndPopulateResults()
Sub ProcessDataAndPopulateResults()
    Dim wb As Workbook
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim rowNum As Integer
    Dim col As Integer
    Dim cellValue As String
    Dim number As Integer
    Dim numCount As Integer
    
    Set wb = Workbooks.Open("document name, for privacy reasos I've removed this")
    Set ws = wb.Sheets(1)
    
    For rowNum = 5 To 75
        For Each cell In ws.Range("AQ" & rowNum & ",AU" & rowNum & ",AY" & rowNum & ",BC" & rowNum & ",BE" & rowNum & ",BV" & rowNum & ",BZ" & rowNum & ",CD" & rowNum & ",CF" & rowNum)
            If Not IsEmpty(cell.Value) Then
                cellValue = CStr(cell.Value)
                If Len(cellValue) > 0 Then
                    If IsNumeric(cellValue) Then
                        number = CInt(cellValue)
                        If number >= 1 And number <= 23 Then
                            numCount = WorksheetFunction.CountIf(ws.Range("AQ" & rowNum & ":CF" & rowNum), number)
                            ws.Cells(rowNum, 83 + number + IIf(InStr(cellValue, "-") > 0, 1, 0)).Value = numCount
                        End If
                    End If
                End If
            End If
        Next cell
    Next rowNum
    
    For rowNum = 5 To 75
        For Each cell In ws.Range("CQ" & rowNum & ":DT" & rowNum)
            If Not IsEmpty(cell.Value) Then
                cellValue = CStr(cell.Value)
                If Len(cellValue) > 0 Then
                    If IsNumeric(cellValue) Then
                        number = CInt(cellValue)
                        If number >= 1 And number <= 23 Then
                            If InStr(cellValue, "-") > 0 Then
                                 ws.Cells(rowNum, 83 + number + 1).Value = 0
                            Else
                                 ws.Cells(rowNum, 83 + number).Value = 1
                            End If
                        End If
                    End If
                End If
            End If
        Next cell
    Next rowNum
    
    wb.Close SaveChanges:=True
End Sub
```

Only when I try to run my script I get the error code " Compile error: Invalid outside procedure"

What can I do to improve my code?

I've tried to save my code under ProcessDataAndpopulateResults but when i try to save it the code will not run

Comment: It sounds as if you could do this in a formula with `COUNTIF` but if you want to do it in a script then first tell us which line of code throus the error

Comment: Also consider uploading screencaps of the data and expected result to http://imgur.com and linking to it, or, even better, posting an editable table of sample data and expected result

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Why do you have twice `Sub ProcessDataAndPopulateResults()` in your code?